# How to append a random string to filenames using Script Editor [Mac OS]

Tags: macos, automator

I have a folder filled with pdf files.

filename_1.pdf
filename_2.pdf
filename_3.pdf
etc...

I am looking for a way to go from those filenames to something like :

filename_1973878763487.pdf
filename_27523765376346.pdf
filename_326537652376523.pdf

I came across the following script that changes filenames to random numbers :

```
  tell application "Finder"
    repeat with this_item in (get items of window 1)
        set name of this_item to ((random number from 1000 to 9999) & "." & name extension of this_item) as string
    end repeat
end tell
```

The script outputs something like this :

3598.pdf
7862.pdf
8365.pdf

So i need a way to append the random numbers to the original filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with thisItem in (get items of window 1)
        set fileName to name of thisItem
        tell current application
            set theOffset to offset of "_" in fileName
        end tell
        set tempFileName to text 1 thru (theOffset + 1) of fileName
        tell current application
            set randomNumber to (random number from 1000 to 9999)
        end tell
        set name of thisItem to tempFileName & (randomNumber & "." & name extension of thisItem) as string
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I tweaked it a little but it is what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @NSTK Just curious what it was that you needed to tweak?  If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: Ah nothing too heavy, just the offset and the range of the random numbers